# Get the Apps name running using Java

Tags: java, process

I get all processes using

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of <code>test</code>.
 */
public test() {
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
           System.out.println(line); 
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But what I only need is to list names of the applications running on windows.

For example, Teamviewer, Google Chrome, etc.

Is it possible using this Java Process? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found best result by using vbscript. Filtering the results from tasklist seems tricky. Try creating a file with **vbs** extension with following content:

```
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)

For Each Task in Tasks
   If Task.Visible  Then 
     stdout.WriteLine Task.Name
   End If
Next
Word.Quit
```

And now just change your code to run cscript instead of tasklist:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript C:\\<path to your vbsfile>\\test.vbs");
```

**Correction:** got rid of Tasks(Task).WindowState=1 from if statement. This filter outs all but maximized windows.

**Note:** Output still is not the same as the task manager. But it is how Microsoft defines to get the app list: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405673.aspx

Comment: still not working this answer. I run it to JCreator, no error but only showing "Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." When I tried to run in cmd, Microoft VBScript runtime error:ActiveX Component cant create object: 'Word Application"

Comment: By the way, I dont have MSword in my windows. Can I do it even I dont have MSWord?

Comment: Unfortunately you need either MSWord or the needed activex components . The second way would be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the names of the tasks in the taskmanager in the "Applications". The names of the applications are those entries in the result of the tasklist command, that have a "Window Title", which you only get running tasklist in verbose mode

```
tasklist.exe /V
```

If you want the result be more easily parseable, you should produce a CSV output use the `/NH` flag to omit display of the header:

```
tasklist.exe /V /NH /FO CSV
```

Now you can extract the 9th element of each line with

```
String[] elements = line.split(",");
if (!"\"N/A\"".equals(elements[8])){
    System.out.println(elements[8]);
}
```

Maybe you need to apply some filtering to the tasklist command to get the exact application, the `tasklist /?` will provide you the details.